# How do I fix a Binding Failure in Soap?

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I reloaded an old project, and tried to run it only to run into the Binding Failure MDA Assistant:

```
BindingFailure was detected 

Message: The assembly with display name 'SoapTest.XmlSerializers' failed to load in the
'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'SoapTest.XmlSerializers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one 
of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After googling this, the only solution I could find was to turn off the MDA.  This works, but I would prefer to solve the underlying problem (SoapTest.XmlSerializers.dll not being in the bin\Debug directory).  How can I fix this?  What creates the SoapTest.XmlSerializers.dll, and why is it not being created on a Rebuild?  Yes, I have tried updating the Web Reference (this doesn't help).  No I don't want to upgrade to WCF Soap Services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually yes , i went to the propensities window and set the option of "Generate serialization assembly" to "on" , by this you insure every time you build the project ,
i guess that error happens when you edit the assmbly info of the class library you are referencing without re building it

Answer (score 1):

In VS.NET you can go to the project settings and try different settings for XmlSerialization - I believe there is a setting for auto that you may want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue. The problem was that the project causing the Exception was created in another folder than the .exe file. I easily resolved it by changing the Deployment Path from Properties/Build settings page. No other change on "Generate serialization assembly" was necessary.