# BindingFailure when calling Service Reference method

Tags: .net, web-services

My `.NET 4.0` project contains a few service references.
One of them if giving problems when calling a service method.
It's a `SOAP` service and when testing with SoapUI i can connect to it and execute methods successfully.

This is the .NET code:

```
var client = new MyNamespace.MyProject.MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient();
client.Open();

var response = client.SaveApplication(request);

client.Close();
```

Opening the connection works fine, but when i call the SaveApplication method, i get the following exception:

> The assembly with display name 'MyNamespace.MyProject.XmlSerializers' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 2. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyNamespace.MyProject.XmlSerializers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I really have no clue to what causes this exception...
Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [How do I fix a Binding Failure in Soap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234515/how-do-i-fix-a-binding-failure-in-soap)
I had to turn off MDA BindingFailure exceptions in Visual Studio because i don't want to add the service as Web Reference.